# Expectation as an Operator vs. as a Functional

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, vector-spaces

I've been reading probability formalisms, and I see people referring to expectation often as an operator, and less often as a functional (in the context of a vector space of random variables).

I can see how $\mathbb{E}: X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a functional, in that it takes $X$, an element of a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and returns an element of that field. But I fail to see how it's an operator; in what sense is the expected value of a random variable itself a function? (Of course, there's the sense in which any constant function $X: \Omega \to \{r\}$ is a random variable, but that doesn't seem "clean" enough to motivate the separate treatment).

Comment: Could you give a reference where the expectation is treated as an operator?

Comment: Well, the conditional expectation $E(\cdot|\mathcal{F})$ is always an operator (sending random variables to random variables). And since $E(X)$ is nothing but $E(X|\{\emptyset, \Omega\})$, it is also an operator in that sense (sending random variables to constants).

Comment: @Sayantan -- Just in general, if you google "expectation operator," you'll run into the kinds of sources I used (not intended to be clever; I googled it too). 

And, re your second point. I see how _conditioning_ is an operator, in that it takes a random variable _X_ and gives you a new one _X|Y_. But conditional **expectation**, IMO, works like a functional; it doesn't give you a new random variable, but rather collapses that variable to a point in the underlying field.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can define $X|Y$ to be *random variable*. But $E(X|Y) := E(X|\sigma(Y))$ is by definition always a random variable. Let me elaborate a bit: assume that $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability space and $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. Then the conditional expectation $E(\cdot|\mathcal{G})$ takes an $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variable $X$ and turns it into a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable. In particular, it works like a orthogonal projection from  $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) $ onto $ L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with the rigorous measure theoretic definition of conditional expectation, do take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition .